# How to post JSON formatted data to Shopify?

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, shopify

For example user from WooCommerce trigers woocommerce_add_to_cart hook is it possible to send product data to Shopify app as json and that data be accepted via Shopify app as carts/create webhook? If so how could I do this?

UPDATE:

Finally found a way of doing that. Here is and example code, for adding order:

```
            $ch = curl_init("https://api_key:api_pass@shop_name.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json");
        $order = array('order' => array(
            'line_items' => array(
                array(
                    'title' => 'Big Brown Bear Boots',
                    'price' => '74.99',
                    'grams' => '1300',
                    'quantity' => 3,
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => 'Clicky Keyboard',
                    'price' => '150',
                    'quantity' => 1,
                )
            )
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($order)); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
```

And you hook this code to woocommerce action.